# How iptables work when DNAT and REDIRECT are both set with the same rule?

Tags: iptables, kubernetes

```
$ iptables -t nat -L -n
Chain KUBE-PORTALS-CONTAINER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
…
REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0    11.1.1.88      /* service-nginx */ tcp dpt:8001 redir ports 43318
Chain KUBE-PORTALS-HOST (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
…
DNAT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0    11.1.1.88    /* service-nginx */ tcp dpt:8001 to:10.10.103.58:43318
```

[update] BTW, 10.10.103.58 is just the IP of eth0 of the local machine.

I saw the answer in [Difference beetween DNAT and REDIRECT in IPTABLES](https://serverfault.com/questions/179200/difference-beetween-dnat-and-redirect-in-iptables), so I know that REDIRECT only work for local redirect.

[update] But my question is, in this cases, Kubernetes set both DNAT and REDIRECT at the same machine, why?

[update] My guess from the chains' name is that `DNAT` will forward any request send from host to `11.1.1.88` to `10.10.103.58:43318`. But for the request send from a container running on this host the `REDIRECT` chain will work instead.

Am I right?

Comment: Could you edit into your question portions of the output of `iptables -L -n -v -t nat` instead (note additional `-v`)?  The packet counts on those rules would be interesting to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to setup both rules. One of them will be enough for same type of traffic.

1. If you want to redirect traffic to local machine (firewall), you can
   use either one. Using `DNAT` may be useful if you want to specify a different IP address on the local machine other than the one picked up by `REDIRECT` in case your machine has multiple IP addresses.
2. If you want to redirect traffic to some other machine, you need
   to use `DNAT` to specify the new destination.

In short, `DNAT` is more general and can be used in all cases.

Comment: And yes, this machine has two IP addresses (eth0 and eth1, see the update), then which one will take effect then?